# Call method after child executes command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm currently learning how to implement Commands into C#/WPF projects. Suppose I have a class `MyClass` with a simple command `MyCommand`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private RelayCommand _myCommand;
    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myCommand == null)
                _myCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => ExecuteMyCommand());
            return _myCommand;
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteMyCommand()
    {
        // Do work...
    }
}
```

Now, suppose I created an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` in a view model, which is bound to a ListView. The ListView has a GridViewColumn with buttons bound to MyCommand. Everything works great.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyClass> _myCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyCollection
    {
        get { return _myCollection; }
        set
        {
            _myCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyCollection");
        }
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        // Do work to refresh MyCollection to it's "live" state
    }
}
```

Now I need to call the Refresh() method on the view model after the one of the objects in MyCollection executes MyCommand, but I'm not sure how to approach this situation.

Things I have tried:

- Adding a reference to the view model during MyClass's construction, allowing the command to call Refresh() on via the view model's reference when the command executes. This works fine but I really don't like the code - it feels messy to have it reference a specific view model, especially when it's used in other parts of the program.

Things I have considered:

- Changing Refresh() to an extension method for `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`, adding a reference property like mentioned previously but referencing the ObservableCollection instead of the view model, which wouldn't feel as messy but still not really perfect in my eyes...

What would be the best/correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: I don't really see a question here...

Comment: @Ben The question was more or less an implied "how should I proceed?", but I've added another line just for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to turn this on is the following:

```
<MenuItem Content="Run MyCommand"
          Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.RefreshCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Then, in your `MyViewModel`

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyClass> _myCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyCollection
    {
        get { return _myCollection; }
        set
        {
            _myCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyCollection");
        }
    }

    //...

    private ICommand _refreshCommand;
    public ICommand RefreshCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_refreshCommand== null)
                _refreshCommand= new RelayCommand<MyClass>(p => Refresh(p));
            return _refreshCommand;
        }
    }

    public void Refresh(MyClass parameter)
    {
        if (null == parameter)
            return;
        parameter.ExecuteMyCommand();
        // Do work to refresh MyCollection to it's "live" state
    }
}
```

Note: currently you do not need to have the `MyCommand` on each `MyClass` instance - you can pass it as a parameter to the parent view model.

I cannot say that there is the *right way* to accomplish your task. So I cannot say which one is better.

Comment: I like this solution even more than mine - I think the commands don't really belong on the collection objects because the class shouldn't hold code that pertains to interacting with the view, so this is very nice. Also, each object won't contain its own instance of the command, which is definitely a good thing. I will attempt to get this working now...

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks so much! I moved all the commands off the collection objects and into the view model, but left the methods that the commands execute on the objects. I'm very happy with this solution!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work in (I think) a pretty nice way.

First of all, I changed Refresh() to a command. I then added a parameter to the MyCommand method. The method does its work, and then checks the parameter to see if it's a command, and then executes it.

```
private void ExecuteMyCommand(object param)
{
    // Do work...
    if (param != null && param is ICommand)
        ((ICommand)param).Execute(null);
}
```

Then in XAML for the View, I set the CommandParameter to the command I want it to run afterwards.

```
<MenuItem Content="Run MyCommand"
          Command="{Binding UploadCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.RefreshCommand}"/>
```

If no CommandParameter is supplied in XAML, it passes null. Done...

Answer (score 0):

You can also put a click event on the buttons (they bubble up to the view), and call the command from code-behind

Comment: While true, I was hoping to move away from using events wherever commands could replace them